# Blocking some keywords (inappropriate words) in Sharepoint 2010 Blogs comments, posts title

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, site-collection

I figured how to block inappropriate words from sharepoint blog posts through workflow. I want to do the same when those keywords appear in posts title or comments.

Comment: G-Man, can you share the source where you find the workflow to block inappropriate words in Blog Posts? Why can't you use same workflow for Comments list?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in ItemUpdating/ItemUpdated, then you could have it run for all lists from the same event receiver.

It would only be available for approval once the filtering is done by ItemUpdated, ItemUpdating would set it as a draft.

Have a hidden list of banned words, the words are stored in regex replacement text for simplicity, then run the list against the values, once done they can be set to be allowed for approval by using a flag column or automatically approved and published.

Comment: That's the workflow which is confusing. I did that for post's body. it works fine. But I don't know how to do it for comments. Its not working. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/d8977d4c-d4ef-47f7-b920-889c061637fd - I used this answer to implement for posts body. but can you tell me for comments?

Comment: It's the comments list, it's a separate list. Get SharePoint manager from codeplex and browse your site to get a better understanding. You can also see where the workflow is attached and how, the column names types, even attach etc.